# Where to save files created programmatically to protect them from updates?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

When I create an image programmatically, I use this type of code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *photoname=@"image.jpeg";
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:photoname];
NSData *data;
UIImage *image= [UIImage imageWithData:[values objectForKey:@"imgdata"]];
data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.4f);
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

I'm wondering, when I'll update the application, these files will be preserved?
If not, how do I?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files in document diretory will not be deleted even when user updates the application (unless user does clean installation).

If you want to take care of the case of clean installation, you have to use iCloud.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is the same for a CoreData database?

Comment: I mean: I create a database using CoreData following the template created by XCode. That database will be deleted after an update?

Comment: No, the template saves the sqlite file in document directory, which will not be deleted unless the user removes the app from the phone.